# Написание функции по moveUp и moveDowm

Tags: javascript, jquery

В консоли у меня все работает. Там для скрола вниз я ввожу:

```
$('.section').moveDown();
```

Для скрола вверх:

```
$('.section').moveUp();
```

Секции то есть меняются. Окей. Дальше хочу прикрепить эти два действия на скрол мыши вверх вниз и на странице получается кошмар. Вот мой пример кода

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
      if (event.originalEvent.deltaY >= 0) {
          $('.section').moveDown()
      }
      else {
          $('.section').moveUp();
      }
  });
```

Как написать скрипт, чтобы отрабатывалось как в консоли? P.S. Скорее всего скролл тригерит слишком много раз, так как в некоторых браузерах он может перекинуть с 1 слайда сразу на 5-й.

Comment: надо добавить `event.preventDefault()`, что бы отменить нативный скролл

Comment: пробовал, не помогло.